# Set row values as column headers in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using this query

```
SELECT 
    ValuationDate, 
    SUM(TotalQuantitySold) AS Units, 
    platformproductid 
FROM 
    TableA 
WHERE
    ValuationDate BETWEEN '01-12-2023' AND '28-12-2023'
GROUP BY 
    valuationdate, platformproductid
```

| ValuationDate | Units | PlatformProductId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-12-01 | 58 | 40006 |
| 2023-12-02 | 69 | 40006 |
| 2023-12-03 | 20 | 40006 |
| 2023-12-01 | 12 | 40010 |
| 2023-12-02 | 1 | 40010 |

But I want the output in this format.

| PlatformProductId | 01-12-2023 | 02-12-2023 | 03-12-2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40006 | 58 | 69 | 20 |
| 40010 | 12 | 1 | 12 |

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Might be below query ll work?

```
SELECT
    platformproductid,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ValuationDate = '2023-12-01' THEN TotalQuantitySold ELSE 0 END) AS Units_2023_12_01,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ValuationDate = '2023-12-02' THEN TotalQuantitySold ELSE 0 END) AS Units_2023_12_02,
    -- Add similar lines for other dates
    SUM(TotalQuantitySold) AS TotalUnits
FROM
    TableA
WHERE
    ValuationDate BETWEEN '2023-12-01' AND '2023-12-28'
GROUP BY
    platformproductid;
```

Comment: I want the dates to come dynamically in the column headers. Because they will change every time. Can I update this query to do that? @Adam Joe

Comment: yes, You can update this query as per your req

Comment: Date Range in the between part will change every time. How will I dynamically update the sql statement every time. @Adam Joe